# Formating a table with columns and row in bash printf

Tags: bash, printf

I have below an output generated by several awk/grep expressions which I have stored in variables. Then I am trying to plot a table for info from those variables. When i have a single value on all my variables everything works and the table shows nicely formatted but with multiple values in these variables my table is messing up. I don't know how to put this nicely.

The relation between the column1 an d column 2 is a 1 to 1 mapping in sequential order because that is how they are stored in the respective variables.

```
echo $tl_user_emails
mapping-aws-dev@team.com jhon@team.com
```

```
echo $tl_user_nmspcs
test-2d7dbabf-f8cc-4c0b-af3b-80db52d2257e test-60cb4076-9280-4cf9-bb34-9f9e4ac8bd20
```

```
printf "\n\n test User Namespaces on node running pods: \n%s" "$tl_user_nmspcs"
printf "\n\n test users running pods on this node:  \n%s\n\n" "$tl_user_emails"
```

```
printf "\n${yellow}${bold}%5sTest User Email${creset}${normal}%15s${yellow}${bold}%5sTest User Namespace${creset}${normal}%23s\n" " " "|" " " "|"
printf "%s %16s|%s%5s|\n" "$tl_user_emails" " " "$tl_user_nmspcs" " "
```

```
test User Namespaces on node running pods:
test-2d7dbabf-f8cc-4c0b-af3b-80db52d2257e
test-60cb4076-9280-4cf9-bb34-9f9e4ac8bd20




test users running pods on this node:
mapping-aws-dev@team.com
jhon@team.com


Above test pods info on this node: node1

output:
     Test User Email                |     Test User Namespace                      |
mapping-aws-dev@team.com
jhon@team.com.                      |test-2d7dbabf-f8cc-4c0b-af3b-80db52d2257e
test-60cb4076-9280-4cf9-bb34-9f9e4ac8bd20   |
```

```
expected output:

     Test User Email                |     Test User Namespace                  |
mapping-aws-dev@team.com            |                                          |
jhon@team.com.                      |test-2d7dbabf-f8cc-4c0b-af3b-80db52d2257e |
                                    |test-60cb4076-9280-4cf9-bb34-9f9e4ac8bd20 |
                                    ||
```

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/605228)

Comment: You have a list of user emails in the first column and a list of name spaces in the second one. What is the correspondance between the two colums? Is there some special relation between `jhon@team.com.` and `test-2d7dbabf-f8cc-4c0b-af3b-80db52d2257e` that you put only this pair on the same line? If so, how do we know on which line the content has to go?

Comment: relation is 1 to 1 mapping for every entry in col1 to every entry in col2 and that is sequential coz that is how they are stored in respective variables

Comment: Please use `declare -p varname` to generate a precise description of your variables' values, and include that in the question. The output of `printf '%s\n' "$varname"` is not sufficient, as it doesn't unambiguously present non-printing characters; we can't tell if there are escape sequences, whitespace, etc present; whereas the output of `declare -p` is code we can run ourselves to define those same variables on a local system, thus enabling someone to confidently test their answers.

Comment: okay: I updated question echoing them during run

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
bold=$(tput bold)
creset=$(tput rmso)
normal=$(tput sgr0)

tl_user_emails='mapping-aws-dev@team.com
jhon@team.com'
tl_user_nmspcs='test-2d7dbabf-f8cc-4c0b-af3b-80db52d2257e
test-60cb4076-9280-4cf9-bb34-9f9e4ac8bd20'

printf "\n${yellow}${bold}%5sTest User Email%16s${creset}${normal}|${yellow}${bold}%5sTest User Namespace%18s${creset}${normal}|\n" # all args after format are empty strings by default

declare -a emails
declare -a namespaces

for e in $tl_user_emails; do emails+=($e); done
for n in $tl_user_nmspcs; do namespaces+=($n); done

format="%-36s|%-42s|\n"

i=0
for e in ${emails[@]}; do
  printf "$format" "$e" "${namespaces[((i++))]}"
done
```

It gives as output (with yellow colors and bold chars wherever needed):

```
     Test User Email                |     Test User Namespace                  |
mapping-aws-dev@team.com            |test-2d7dbabf-f8cc-4c0b-af3b-80db52d2257e |
jhon@team.com                       |test-60cb4076-9280-4cf9-bb34-9f9e4ac8bd20 |
```